# Set multiple website path for an EC2 instance in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx

Trying to understand Nginx configuration. I have two websites in the folder /var/www inside my test EC2 instance.

```
|
|-website1
|-website2
```

I am trying to configure the nginx and the IP address of the instance is 35.52.135.20.

The default configuration is for website1 and the server name is given as the IP address as below

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name 35.52.135.20;
  root /var/www/website1/;
}
```

Now I need to configure the second configuration for website2, what do I give as server_name in the configuration? In all the examples I read, domain names like www.abcd.com etc are given but I do not own any domain name currently so what do I give for the second website?

Comment: The server_name directive is really only needed to specify the hostname a virtual host should respond to, such as when you have 2 different domain names pointing to the same IP address. If you are not using any domain names, neither server needs a server_name value, but they will have to differ in the address or port they listen on.

Comment: @mjb2kmn So I set listen as 81 in the next config file, and access it by 35.52.135.20:81? Is that the way to do it?

Comment: yes, that sounds right. If you haven't yet, check out https://nginx.org/en/docs/ for some decent guides and very thorough documentation.